# What does mkdir -p do? specifically the "-p" part?

Tags: terminal, mac, unix, software

I have had some trouble understanding when manipulating my Terminal with the making of directories, and I've encountered with this "-p" option in the network trying to find easier ways to create directories. Any help? :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried running the `man mkdir` command in Terminal? Doing so results in the following explanation for the `-p` option:

> Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is
>                not specified, the full path prefix of each operand must already
>                exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no error
>                will be reported if a directory given as an operand already
>                exists.  Intermediate directories are created with permission
>                bits of rwxrwxrwx (0777) as modified by the current umask, plus
>                write and search permission for the owner.

So basically

```
mkdir foo/bar/baz/quizz
```

will fail unless the directories `foo`, `foo/bar` and `foo/bar/baz` already exist.

```
mkdir -p  foo/bar/baz/quizz
```

will create any missing directories in the path (as long as you have write permissions in the parent directory) *and* ensure that the permissions allow you to access them.

Comment: Thank you so much!, now I get it hahaha, anyways, I'll try and keep up learning :D